# Use VPN that runs in Docker Image with the entire Mac

Tags: macos, vpn, docker

I have a running VPN on an Ubuntu Image in Docker. I can confirm, that the VPN is running successfully confined in the Docker environment. I would like to use this VPN that is running in Docker now for my entire Mac. Can somebody assist me with that setup?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think this is specific enough! Running VPN inside of Docker. Use it outside of docker on entire system (which is macOS)

Comment: Which VPN? Where does the other end of the VPN connect to? What Mac OS version? How are you connecting to the internet? Are you behind a firewall? What do you mean "the entire Mac"? Which Ubuntu Docker Image? Have you built this yourself or followed a tutorial?

Comment: For what reason you're not creating the VPN in the host?